# Editing Build.scala in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to migrate our build from maven to SBT, so now I work separatedly on `Build.scala` file. However I don't benefit from any syntax highlighting (that is quite obvious, I don't have SBT in my classpath). What is the correct way to get SBT to my classpath, adding `sbt-launch.jar` does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what I did is finished to write my `build.sbt` stub, and opened a project with it. Now everything seem to work.

Comment: That's excellent. That means you probably don't need to run the sbt gen-idea plugin anymore if you're using IntelliJ 13.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ 13 has [built-in SBT support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/scala.html); if you're running a lower version, then you can have a look at their [sbt plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5007?pr=idea).

There's also [an sbt plugin on github for generating idea project files](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea). I've had success with running the `gen-idea` task it provides.

Run sbt `gen-idea`. It will create a `"YOUR_PROJECT_NAME - build"` project within your main project (for whatever your `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` happens to be). Under the `project` folder of the build project, I was able to write a Build.scala with the following code:

```scala
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {

}
```

The SBT Build trait is recognized just fine. I'm running IntelliJ 13 build #IU-133-696, Scala plugin 0.30.378.

Comment: I use v13, but on line `object ProjectBuild extends Build` - the `Build` trait is red (however there is `import sbt._`).

Comment: @yevgeniymordovkin scala plugin version?